# Angularjs oauth Error: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Authorization: Bearer ' is not a valid HTTP header field name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth

My code for making GET call is

```js
$http({
  url: '/user/info/',
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    'Authorization: Bearer ': String(JSON.parse($cookies.authenticatedAccount).access_token)
  },
  withCredentials: true
});
```

With the above code getting issue: "Error: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Authorization: Bearer ' is not a valid HTTP header field name."

Any idea what may be issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
...
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+String(JSON.parse($cookies.authenticatedAccount).access_token)
},
...
```