# Why can't angular2/http set header during development on webpack?

Tags: typescript, angular, http-headers, webpack-dev-server

Setting the header works when I build the project's war via gradle and deploy it to tomcat, but for some reason, when I spin up webpack's development server for testing, I get the error:

```
EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 
'XMLHttpRequest': 'Bearer xxx.yyy.zzz' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
in [null] (browser_adapter.ts:73).
```

The frustrating thing is this has been intermittent. First I had a JWT that was only 'xxx.yyy' and it worked. Then all of a sudden it didn't. Then I realized I might need to include a fake signature. So I changed it to 'xxx.yyy.zzz' and it worked! Then all of a sudden it didn't. Then I thought maybe the fake signature still had to be the appropriate length for the rest of the JWT. So I increased the length, and it worked. Now it doesn't.

Here's my dev-proxy-settings.js:

```
module.exports = {
    settings: {
        '/*': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here's my use of angular2/http

```
import {Headers, Http, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
import {RequestOptions, Response} from 'angular2/http';

...

var headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx.yyy.zzz'
});
var options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers,
    method: RequestMethod.Get,
    url: '/some/url'
});
let httpResponse = this.http.request(options.url, options).map(...);
```

Am I missing something??

Comment: Sounds similar https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/98, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823781/angularjs-oauth-error-failed-to-execute-setrequestheader-on-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Did you actually try with `xxx.yyy.zzz` as bearer token value or only with generated values. The generated value might contain invalid characters.

Comment: I used `Bearer eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.blablablafakesignatureblablablanotrealblabl`. The only part I changed was the signature, but the rest I left as generated by my server code, which works when I actually deploy it. But for some reason fails when I'm using the dev-proxy-server.

Comment: Wrapping the token in String() didn't fix the problem

Comment: Crap. I guess one of those characters is invalid. I replaced it with a bunch of 'e's and it's working. Of course it was working before too, so I'm sure in a couple days it'll suddenly start failing again.

Comment: I think I'm just gonna delete this question, thanks for your help Gunter

Comment: No need to delete. Would be great if you could post how you solved it after you figured it out what character was invalid.

Comment: Hahaha, and now it's magically stopped working again. This would be funny if it wasn't so annoying. But I think I've figured out a work around - change the signature every time web-pack's server suddenly decides it no longer likes the header. I'm not sure what goes wrong, that web pack's dev server initially accepts and then eventually rejects a valid header, but just editing the header each time seems fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fake signature I added had an invalid character. I'm not sure which character wasn't allowed, but the fake signature I used was `blablablafakesignatureblablablanotrealblabl`. Changing it to `eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` fixed it.

I also added a description of allowed headers to my webpack config file's devServer configuration. Not sure if that helped too, but I'm not seeing that error anymore.

```
devServer: {
    port: metadata.port,
    host: metadata.host,
    // contentBase: 'src/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
    },
    proxy: proxySettings.settings
},
```

Comment: Hahaha, and now it's magically stopped working again. This would be funny if it wasn't so annoying. But I think I've figured out a work around - change the signature every time web-pack's server suddenly decides it no longer likes the header. I'm not sure what goes wrong, that web pack's dev server initially accepts and then eventually rejects a valid header, but just editing the header each time seems fix it.